# com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: Too many parameters -- symbol table overflow

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I am using jconn2.jar(5.5) jdbc driver for Sybase to connect 
to a sybase database from a standalone java application. 
My java application will read thousands of 
records from a text file and insert in to the table in the 
sybase database. 
I have a select query with IN clause.This IN clause will have more than 10,000 values. while executing this query, the 
application is returning the below error:

> Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybSQLException: Too many  parameters
>   -- symbol table overflow.
>
> at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:3281)  at
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:2548)  at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:69) 
>   at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:220) 
>   at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:203) 
>   at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java:1614) 
>   at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:1599)
>   at 
>   com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:96)
>
> at 
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
>
> at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:648)
>
> at 
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:591)
>   ... 10 more

The same query is working well for values in IN clause with 
up to 10,000 values.

I tried with jconnect6 and jconnect7. but same result.

Anyone is having any idea, why it's 
returning the error like above for the values having more 
than 10,000?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably just because there is a hard limit on the number of elements in an IN clause. Oracle's limit is 1000.

Comment: As per the sybase manual, the IN clause in sybase can have upto 2,50,000 elements.                        http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.ase.15.0.3/title.htm             Number of values in an IN list      250,000

Comment: Then the hard limit is perhaps not on the numer of elements in an IN clause, but in the number of parameters in a prepared statement. That's, by the way, the message of the exception: "Too many parameters -- symbol table overflow".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've simply hit a hard limit?  I wouldn't recommend an IN condition with that many values: if you need that many, you're doing something quite inadvisable in your SQL and it could be time to look at a refactor...?

Comment: Initially i thought like that. But the sybase manual tells that the IN clause in Sybase can have up to 2,50,000.

Comment: It's maybe a hard limit in JDBC layer rather than Sybase. If 9,999 works though and 10,000 doesn't, it really suggests you've hit a limit. And there are better ways to handle this 10,000+ values design, e.g. a subquery, use a temp table.

Comment: It's not exactly the number 10,000. I put it approx. No issues if the no. of values are 10,000+. But not working with the values 11,000+

Comment: You might be best focusing on the fact that this is a limit hitting you from *some* layer, and an IN condition with that many participants is a very very undesirable solution and is in fact not working, and look at a possible refactor. Do you know about JOINs in SQL?